# Value of attribute 'title' has changed. How to make tooltip understand it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tooltip

When I hover the element with the class `.notice`, tooltip shows me **blue**. When I hover it again, then it shows me whatever Ajax is returning.

```
        <script>
            $(".notice").tooltip();
            $(".notice").mouseover(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/wp-content/themes/your-click/ajax-request.php",
                    data: { comment_id_tooltip: $(this).attr("id") },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $(".notice").attr("title", result);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
<td><i title="blue" id="' . $get_uncontacted_member->id . '" class="fa fa-comment-o notice comment_form"></i></td>
```

How can I get rid of this 'blue' and make tooltip start showing the content of Ajax from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the tooltip on load instead of on mouseover.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/wp-content/themes/your-click/ajax-request.php",
        data: { comment_id_tooltip: $('.notice').attr("id") },
        success: function(result) {
        $(".notice").attr("title", result);
        $(".notice").tooltip();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<td><i title="blue" id="' . $get_uncontacted_member->id . '" class="fa fa-comment-o notice comment_form"></i></td>
```